# Tool pylint failed to run (exception was raised) Python

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, lint, pylint

I am getting an error in static analysis when I insert init.py file in my root directory.If I remove init.py file error is resolved but I need init.py file.

My project structure is :
api:
apps:
module1
module2
init.py

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
Go to the apps directory
Call prospector the following properties :
strictness: veryhigh
output-format: pylint
autodetect: false
doc-warnings: true
member-warnings: true
test-warnings: false
max-line-length: 120
ignore-paths:

documentation
requirements
tests
migrations
build-env
uses:
django
vulture:
run: false
bandit:
run: true
mccabe:
options:
max-complexity: 10
pep8:
full: true
disable:
    E203
    pep257:
    disable:
    D104
    D203
    D212
    pylint:
    full: true
    disable:
    relative-beyond-top-level
    import-outside-toplevel
    options:
    good-names:
        c
        e
        ignore: "migrations|tests"

Error occured :
Tool pylint failed to run (exception was raised) error in static analysis.
```

Expected behavior
Pylint should run successfully.

Environment:

```
OS: Windows 10
Pylint version 2.5.2
Prospector version 1.3.0
Python version 3.8.5
```

Comment: What exception exactly is raised? is it possible to debug it and get more info so we could help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply man but I solved the problem. It was happening due to a string assignment which it wasnt showing. I opened every file to check the lint issue and found one. It seems this line was creating lint to fail

user="User.user"

So I put the string into a constant and then assigned it to user and it solved the problem of lint failure